# Values file having duplicated values by the build tools

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

When I take off incremental build when am wanting to do a release for the customer its giving me a few errors and am not sure why. This is when I click build and then archive the andriod version

[image]

If I look at the values.xml file in question I do not see any issues. If it is duplicating them its not me doing it its the build tools themselves
am on 17.1.2. Visual Studio

I checked  all the folder names as other suggestions on here and no issues with weird accents at all

Contents of the values.xml

https://pastebin.com/0BNCrRt6

```
   <!-- translation in x of the view. This value is added post-layout to the left
             property of the view, which is set by its layout. -->
        <attr name="android:translationX"/>
        <!-- translation in y of the view. This value is added post-layout to the top
             property of the view, which is set by its layout. -->
        <attr name="android:translationY"/>
        <!-- translation in z of the view. This value is added to its elevation. -->
        <attr name="android:translationZ"/>
        <!-- Specifies the basic width of the view.  This is a required attribute
             for any view inside of a containing layout manager.  Its value may
             be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant width or one of
             the special constants. -->
        <attr name="android:layout_width"/>
        <!-- Specifies the basic height of the view.  This is a required attribute
             for any view inside of a containing layout manager.  Its value may
             be a dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant height or one of
             the special constants. -->
        <attr name="android:layout_height"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the start side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive.-->
        <attr name="layout_constraintWidth"/>
        <attr name="layout_constraintHeight"/>
        <attr name="android:layout_marginStart"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the bottom side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive.-->
        <attr name="android:layout_marginBottom"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the top side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive.-->
        <attr name="android:layout_marginTop"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the end side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive.-->
        <attr name="android:layout_marginEnd"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the left side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive. -->
        <attr name="android:layout_marginLeft"/>
        <!--  Specifies extra space on the right side of this view.
              This space is outside this view's bounds.
              Margin values should be positive.-->
        <attr name="android:layout_marginRight"/>
```

Only pasted as pastebin cause of the size of the file.

Comment: Hope this thread https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3896 is helpful!

Comment: Their is nothing missing in my case @AlexandarMay-MSFT it builds

Comment: Have U follow this document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=macos to do a release?